# Call a script from a command that starts a new shell

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line

Using Ubuntu 20.04. I can disable Overlay file system by manually calling a command which creates a shell, then calling a second script from within this new shell. However I would like to be able to script it so I can auto update a pc.

Here are the two scripts I run to diable OverlayFS:

Script 1: Open a shell that allows permanent changes (overlayroot-chroot creates a new shell)

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# Enter chroot mode, which allows one to make permanent changes to / parition

echo "Enter mood to make permanent changes"
echo "Press CTRL+D to exit when finished editing"
sudo overlayroot-chroot
```

Script 2: Make the changes

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# Disable OverlayFS

echo "Disable overlayfs (read only file system at /)"
FILE=/etc/overlayroot.conf
cat << EOF | sudo tee $FILE
overlayroot_cfgdisk="disabled"
overlayroot=""
EOF

echo "COMPLETE."
echo "Press CTRL+D to exit chroot mode."
echo "Then 'sudo reboot' for the changes to take effect."
```

Script 2 needs to run within the shell that script 1 created.

But how does one pass the command to run into the new created shell?

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't work. Each script spawns a new shell with it's own PID.
I would create a bash function in script2.sh and source script2 in script1.
Call the function from script2 in script1.

**script1**

```
source ./script2.sh
# call the function
do_stuff
```

**script2**

```
do_stuff() {
  echo "hello world"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, sourcing an important part. The problem was inside script1, is a 3rd party command that I can't change, that needs to run script 2, but a simple echo did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by simply echoing the command to run into overlayroot-chroot (which I have not had success with before):

```bsh
echo "source /home/path/to/overlayfs/disable.sh" | sudo overlayroot-chroot
```